# Export MySQL data to CSV with Thai language support

Tags: php, mysql, csv, thai

I am trying to export data from mysql database to a CSV file, but Thai content is being displayed as `????s`. Also, in database it's not taking whatever I enter. If I enter `ปดิวรัดา` , it's saving as `à¸›à¸”à¸´à¸§à¸£à¸±à¸”à¸²`

Please help me.

EDIT: Now, i edited encoding of table and fields to `utf8_general_ci` and its storing data as i entered into database but still export problem exists.

Original code we have written is here

Comment: What's encoding of your database?

Comment: Check this link http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: How do you open the export file to check its contents?

Comment: since i am exporting to csv, i am using MS Excel to see its contents and its showing ????s

Answer (score 0):

Set your database encoding to `utf8_general_ci`

Also check that your column with strings has encoding `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Hello,
I just changed both database encoding and column encoding to `utf8_general_ci` and now its storing data as i entered, but when i try to export, its still showing me ????s... what encoding format i should set in `header('Content-Type: text/csv;');` ?

Comment: Yep, you can set the header. Encode your csv file into utf-8. There must be some option to do that.

Comment: I am already setting it to utf-8, but when i do that its returning ?????s instead of characters.

Comment: Let the file be empty, then convert to utf-8, then use the script.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the beginning if the `$buffer` you're exporting:

```
$buffer = chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . $buffer;
```

The encoding is UTF with BOM, adding this will add the BOM.

Comment: This added extra characters at the end like `ï»¿`

Comment: Put this in the headers:

`header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8;');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8;');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");`

Comment: Its returning ????s, i think we need to change UTF-8 to something like `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Did you add the BOM?
`chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191)`

Comment: I don't understand what is BOM?
I appened them to database field value string and its adding some extra letters at the end

Comment: [See this regarfing BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
Add to your question the PHP code that handles the export.

Comment: In the start of `echocsv` add `echo chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191);`

Comment: Yes, i have added but its only adding some strange characters at the starting